# enabe/disable jquery ui components

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, disabled-control

i want to enable/disable a slider every time a button is clicked.

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/4859/):

```
<div id="points" style="width:50px; margin-top: 17px; height:5px "></div>

<button id="lines" type="button" style="width:75px; height: 30px; margin-top:7px">lines</button>

$(function () {
    $("#points").slider({
        value: 100,
        min: 1,
        max: 100,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
        }
    });
    $('.ui-slider').slider('disable');
    $('.ui-slider-handle').height(12);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your fiddle

```
$("#lines").click(function () {
    var disabled = $( ".ui-slider" ).slider( "option", "disabled" );
    $('.ui-slider').slider("option", "disabled", !disabled);
});
```

Comment: hi hamed, your solution works for fiddle but not in my code. I copied it exactly. Do you have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Hi gimba, I copied your code from fiddle and tested, it is working for me locally, what error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery code:

```
$('#lines').click(function(){
  if($('.ui-slider').hasClass('ui-slider-disabled'))
     $('.ui-slider').slider('enable');
  else
     $('.ui-slider').slider('disable');
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/4861/